# How can I use one function to modify different HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in my code and I wanted to make changes to the quantity section. This is what it looks like:

[image: quantity section]

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <i style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="arttir()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i>
        <input type="button" id="sonuc" value="0"/>
        <i onclick="azalt()" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i>
        <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can" onclick="urunsilme()"></i>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have this code but I have it only works for first row of table:

```js
function arttir() {
    var sonuc = document.getElementById("sonuc");
    sonuc.value = Number(sonuc.value) + 1;
}

function azalt() {
    var sonuc = document.getElementById("sonuc");
    if (sonuc.value > 0) {
        sonuc.value = Number(sonuc.value) - 1;
    }
}
```

What can i do in this situation?

Comment: Instead of using a specific ID, you have to make it search for the textbox closest to the item which was clicked. You could make that easier by putting the ID of the related textbox in a data-attribute of the clickable icon. You must make sure each textbox has a unique ID, of course.

Comment: _"I will add picture to show how it looks"_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text"_ -> [mcve]

Comment: You can give `arttir()` and `azalt()` a parameter with the id of the element to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have different html elements having the same id and by the way, the strategy of selecting the element having a given id cannot return a different element by magic depending on the rows.

You need to retrieve, inside your event listener, the element that triggered the click event. Here in this demo I used `window.event.target`. This demo just shows a scenario having two rows where each plus and minus button will trigger the increase/decrease of the value corresponding to each row.

```js
function arttir() {
  const clickedElement = window.event.target;
  const sonuc = clickedElement.closest('td').querySelector('input');
  sonuc.value = Number(sonuc.value) + 1;
}

function azalt() {
  const clickedElement = window.event.target;
  const sonuc = clickedElement.closest('td').querySelector('input');
  if (sonuc.value > 0) {
    sonuc.value = Number(sonuc.value) - 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<table>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <i style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="arttir()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i>
      <input type="button" value="0" />
      <i onclick="azalt()" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i>
      <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can" onclick="urunsilme()"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <i style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="arttir()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i>
      <input type="button" value="0" />
      <i onclick="azalt()" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i>
      <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can" onclick="urunsilme()"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("sonuc")` will return the first element with "sonuc" id.

You need to use `document.getElementsByClassName('yourclassname')`, then iterate over each element and set the value on each of them.

something like

```
function arttir() {
    let sonuc = document.getElementByClassName("sonuc");
    sonuc.forEach(elem=>elem.value = Number(sonuc.value) + 1);
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it's me misunderstanding the question or if this answer doesn't get the point. Aren't you supposed to act only on the row where the event triggered? What's the point of having different rows and each one having their own buttons if I was wrong? And I'm surprised to even see an upvote

Comment: @sadhna  I think you r misunderstanding the question